# Git markdown not taken into account in gitlab? My commit message is displayed as plain text

Tags: git, gitlab

I've prepared the commit file below, then committed it by a `git commit -F commitMessage.md` and pushed it to *Gitlab*, with the other files of the commit.

```
Apprentissage
# Informatique

   - Documents re-répartis pour permettre d'autres divisions
   - elk.md devient : `elk-01-installation-et-configuration`, `elk-02-elasticsearch`, `elk-03-logstash`, `elk-04-kibana`, `elk-05-filebeat-metricsbeat`.
 
# Mathématiques

   - Fonctions et applications >> `mathematiques-05-les-applications`

# Statistiques

   - Documents re-répartis pour permettre d'autres divisions
   - Les tests statistiques et hypothèses >> `statistiques_05-les-tests-statistiques-et-hypotheses`
   - hypothèses fortes et faibles (tests unilatéral ou bilatéral) >> `statistiques_05-les-tests-statistiques-et-hypotheses`
   - La comparaison d'échantillons (par moyenne) >> `statistiques_06-la-comparaison-echantillons`
   - Probabilités : passe du document 04 au `statistiques_40-les-probabilités`

# Territoire

   - Gestion des Milieux Aquatiques et Prévention des Inondations (GEMAPI) >> `territoire-13-environnement`
   - Union Européenne : opérations et programmes opérationnels >>  `territoire-14-UE-operations-po-fonds-européens`
   - Union Européenne : les fonds européens >>  `territoire-14-UE-operations-po-fonds-européens`
   - Union Européenne : les stratégies européennes >>  `territoire-15-UE-les-stratégies-européennes`
```

But *Gitlab* doesn't start the markdown conversion of that commit message. For example :

- `#` starting lines aren't converted to headers
- content under ticks ` don't see a special format applied to them.

[image]

A `git config --list` on my computer doesn't show something special (I didn't asked to replace `#` characters by something else for example).
And I don't think that my *GitLab* account is specially configured.

I must be facing something simple, but what is it?

Comment: What leads you to believe that commit messages should be able to be interpreted as markdown?

Comment: Yeah, why do you think GitLab should _detect_ plain text as Markdown? GitHub also does not support what you're trying GitLab to do. Note that `git config` is a local tool, and there is nothing to tell a "MIME type" of commit messages. Probably (I don't believe it, though) GitLab can be suggested to interpret plain text as Markdown by using Git commit message trailers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simply isn't a feature of GitLab. Markdown *files* are rendered in GitLab's file viewer, but commit messages do not support any particularly special formatting.

Some content in commit messages, like MR/issue references (e.g. `!123`) and URLs may get hyperlinked in the UI, but that's about it as far as commit messages go.

It probably wouldn't be a practical feature to support markdown in commit messages, either. Commit messages are intended to be consumed/readable in many different platforms and tools, including git command line, various git gui software, all flavors of git servers, etc. Allowing markdown in one product could make it difficult to read commit messages in another tool. This has been a long-standing argument against such implementations.

As far as I know, there aren't really any git servers that support rendering markdown from commit messages.

As a possible alternative, you may consider something like [what gitlab does with their changelog.md](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/development/changelog.html) and [git trailers](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-interpret-trailers) (for the GitLab open source project itself).

Comment: Yeah, absolutely. There is no such a thing as git commit message MIME type suggesting a git-friendly tool to render it _somehow_. Also, such a Markdown viewer can be also implemented as a browser extension, but I don't believe it's worth implementing it.